# No me añade los usuarios a los grupos en django

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando con django y al momento de agregar usuarios a grupos con permisos, el sistema me añade el nuevo usuario y crea el grupo pero el usuario no queda en ese grupo. Nose a que se debe esto ya que parece que el sistema esta funcionando correctamente y no me da ningun error al momento de ejecutar el formulario y agregar el nuevo usuario
Estas son las lineas de código que use en views.py y forms.py:

```
def registroEmpleado(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistroEmpleadoForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()

            EmpleadoGroup1=Group.objects.get_or_create(name='EmpleadoGroup')

            ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Proveedor, Boleta_servicio, Producto, Reserva_hora, Situacion_e, User)

            permiso1, c1 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_add_proveedor', name='Puede añadir proveedor', content_type=ct)
            permiso2, c2 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_change_proveedor', name='Puede cambiar proveedor', content_type=ct)
            permiso3, c3 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_delete_proveedor', name='Puede borrar proveedor', content_type=ct)
            permiso4, c4 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_view_proveedor', name='Puede listar proveedor', content_type=ct)
            permiso5, c5 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_add_boleta_servicio', name='Puede añadir boleta de servicio', content_type=ct)
            permiso6, c6 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_change_boleta_servicio', name='Puede cambiar boleta de servicio', content_type=ct)
            permiso7, c7 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_delete_boleta_servicio', name='Puede borrar boleta de servicio', content_type=ct)
            permiso8, c8 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_view_boleta_servicio', name='Puede lista boleta de servicio', content_type=ct)
            permiso9, c9 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_add_producto', name='Puede añadir producto', content_type=ct)
            permiso10, c10 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_change_producto', name='Puede cambiar producto', content_type=ct)
            permiso11, c11 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_delete_producto', name='Puede borrar producto', content_type=ct)
            permiso12, c12 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_view_producto', name='Puede listar producto', content_type=ct)
            permiso13, c13 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_add_reserva_de_hora', name='Puede añadir reserva de hora', content_type=ct)
            permiso14, c14 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_change_reserva_de_hora', name='Puede cambiar reserva de hora', content_type=ct)
            permiso15, c15 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_delete_reserva_de_hora', name='Puede borrar reserva de hora', content_type=ct)
            permiso16, c16 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_view_reserva_de_hora', name='Puede listar reserva de hora', content_type=ct)
            permiso17, c17 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_add_situacion_e', name='Puede añadir situacion e', content_type=ct)
            permiso18, c18 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_change_situacion_e', name='Puede cambiar situacion e', content_type=ct)
            permiso19, c19 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_delete_situacion_e', name='Puede borrar situacion e', content_type=ct)
            permiso20, c20 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_view_situacion_e', name='Puede listar situacion e', content_type=ct)
            permiso21, c21 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_add_user', name='Puede añadir usuario', content_type=ct)
            permiso22, c22 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_change_user', name='Puede cambiar usuario', content_type=ct)
            permiso23, c23 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_delete_user', name='Puede borrar usuario', content_type=ct)
            permiso24, c24 =Permission.objects.get_or_create(codename='can_view_user', name='Puede listar usuario', content_type=ct)
            
            EmpleadoGroup1.permissions.add(permiso1, permiso2, permiso3, permiso4, permiso5, permiso6, permiso7, permiso8, permiso9, permiso10, permiso11, permiso12, permiso13, permiso14, permiso15, permiso16, permiso17, permiso18, permiso19, permiso20, permiso21, permiso22, permiso23, permiso24)
            User.groups.add(EmpleadoGroup1)
            


            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = RegistroEmpleadoForm()


    return render(request, 'registration/registroEmpleado.html', {'form': form})
```

```
class RegistroEmpleadoForm(UserCreationForm):
     first_name = forms.CharField()
     last_name = forms.CharField()
     email = forms.EmailField()

     class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1' ,'password2' )
```

El sistema esta haciendo todo menos agregar el nuevo usuario al grupo que se asigna en el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Debes añadir el usuario al grupo con:

```
EmpleadoGroup1.user_set.add(form.instance)
```